# Can't get "remote-exec" to startup tomcat

Tags: tomcat, terraform, apache-tomee, oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

When provisioning an instance, I am using "remote-exec" to execute some commands and then start up a tomcat instance through terraform.  It looks something like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "mount_fss_on_DFSrvr" {
depends_on = ["oci_core_instance.DFSrvr",
  "oci_file_storage_export.export_FileListener_FileListenerMount",
]

count = "${var.proddfsrvr_count}"

provisioner "remote-exec" {
  connection {
    agent       = false
    timeout     = "15m"
    host        = "${oci_core_instance.DFSrvr.*.public_ip[count.index % var.proddfsrvr_count]}"
    user        = "opc"
    private_key = "${file(var.ssh_private_key)}"
  }

  inline = [
   "some commands",
    "./catalina.sh start",
    "exit"
  ]
}
```

}

The output shows that tomcat was started, but when I look on the instance, the logs show that it hasn't been started(there is no logging).  I can ssh into the instance and run "./catalina.sh start" and it works fine.  I have also tried creating a service and running "sudo service tomee start" instead of "./catalina.sh start" in the remote-exec inline command, and that doesn't work either.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
  null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4
null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Using CATALINA_HOME:   /apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4
null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4/temp
null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Using CLASSPATH:       /apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4/bin/bootstrap.jar:/apache-tomee-plus-7.0.4/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
null_resource.mount_fss_on_DFSrvr[1] (remote-exec): Tomcat started.
```

Comment: is "catalina.sh" has executable bit? maybe you can try "sh catalina.sh start". seems that you shoul add parameters to "remote-exec" [link] (https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html)

Comment: @Aleksei Kurepin Yes, it is executable.  I can ssh into the instance after and run it just fine.  And the output that I posted shows that it ran successfully and Tomcat started. "sh catalina.sh start" does not work either.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but while running a python web app. I guess the issue here is when you run the commands through remote-exec, it exits out of the shell once completed. So when you ssh into the machine it opens through a new shell, you should prefix nohup to your command and I believe that should do the trick. That did it for me though. Use & if you want it to run on background and come out of remote-exec.
Also, you might want to add a "sleep 20" to the inline commands, this would give tomcat time to startup before the provisioner exits.

inline = [
   "some commands",
    "nohup ./catalina.sh start &",
    "sleep 20",
  ]

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it the absolute path rather than `./` something like `source ~/tmp/catalina.sh`. It might not start where you think.

Second remove the `exit` line. It might be exiting before the installation is complete. Some things finish before writing to the disk. You could also try `source ~/path/catalina; sync`

Also, does this need sudo permissions at all?

Comment: I have tried both those things(absolute path and no exit).  Also, I do cd to the path before I call the script, I just didn't show that part. I can ssh into the instance after it is provisioned under the same user and execute the exact command and it works, so no permission problems.  What's puzzling is I get output that Tomcat started, but it has not.

Comment: You may need to explicitly state what type of connection you are using. That would be my only other guess. ```connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "vm-user"
      host        = "${var.puppet_master_hostname}"
      private_key = "${file(var.vm_user_private_key)}"
    }```